# Disable function-level warning using attributes (not pragmas)

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Say that you had the following code:

```
/*
 * Disables missing prototype warnings as function definition
 * will be present in BTF.
 */
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-prototypes"

void has_external_linkage(void)
{
    printf("Called\n");
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The pragmas above will prevent the compiler from emitting a `-Wmissing-prototypes` warning for the specified function. This works fine for a lot of code, but it would be nice if it could be done using function attributes instead, e.g. something like:

```
void __attribute__((nowarn("-Wmissing-prototypes"))) has_external_linkage(void)
{
    printf("Called\n");
}
```

This would be useful, for example, for functions that (as implied in the comment above) expect their type information to be exported in [BTF](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/btf.html) rather than via a signature.

Is something like this currently possible?

**Note**: of course, a header file would work for some users here, but that's not always an option (and it's immaterial to the question). For example, some BPF programs will call kfuncs that are implemented in the kernel. Those kfuncs do *not* have static linkage, and are not exported via a header file due to them explicitly not being exported as part of UAPI due to having no ABI stability guarantees.

In general, this question is *not* about `-Wmissing-prototypes` specifically. It's a general question about disabling warnings for specific functions using a function attribute.

Comment: Why not provide a header file with the declaration and include that? If it's not supposed to be publicly available, just make it `static`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo a header file might not always be an option. For example, in a BPF program, you may want to call into a kfunc (https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/kfuncs.html) that's implemented in the kernel, and _not_ exported via UAPI as it doesn't have any ABI stability guarantees.

Comment: It says it's not necessary to provide prototypes for the kfuncs, but I can't see anything prohibiting it. The page also contains an example how to silence _all_ diagnostic messages for function definitions lacking prototypes. Wouldn't that be an option for these functions?

Comment: I mean sure, you could define a prototype, but what’s the point if nothing in the kernel is linking against it? It’s a symbol that’s meant to be used only by BPF programs. If you defined a prototype, it would be for no other purpose than to silence this warning. I’ll reiterate again: the point is not how to fix the warning. It’s how to *disable* the warning using function attributes. I just used that as an example.

Comment: Exactly, so in that case, why not use the option to silence all of them with `__diag_ignore_all`? Or compile with `-Wno-missing-prototypes`

Comment: You mean why not use a pragma?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250058/discussion-between-byte-lab-and-ted-lyngmo).